# Using Angularjs How to store data inside the controller within the same Page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Please Help me How can i save data in Array and display in Table Within the Form

```
<div ng-app="farmerapp" ng-controller="RegController">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x._Cetificate.CertificateName,new { data_ng_model = "_Cetificate.CertificateName"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x._Cetificate.CertificateName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x._Cetificate.Year, new { data_ng_model = "_Cetificate.Year" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x._Cetificate.Year) <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Btncertification" ng-click="GetFormerData()" value="Save Certificat" />

    <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="abc in MYdata">
                <td>{{abc.CertificateName}}</td>
                <td>{{abc.Year}}</td>

            </tr>
    </table>
```

MY js Code

```
$scope.GetFormerData = function () {
    $scope.MYdata = [];
    $scope.MYdata.push($scope._Cetificate);
}
```

Please Help me Here im Completly new

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for doing this.

The simplest one (that I recommend) is to make an ajax call to your API (inside `RegController`) in order to fetch your data, and then putting the results into `MYData`.

Another option would be to serialize your object using Razor's `Html.Raw()`

```
$scope.MYData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.DataValues));
```